# Validate webhook from Podio

Tags: php, webhooks, podio

i'm creating a PHP script to integrate with Podio.. I think i have all right, but i can't verify the webhook from the Podio website.. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong? This is my code:

```
require_once '../lib/Podio/PodioAPI.php';
require_once '../lib/Podio/__cfg.php';
Podio::setup(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

if (!Podio::is_authenticated()) {
  Podio::authenticate('app', array('app_id' => APP_ID, 'app_token' => APP_TOKEN)); 
}

if ($_POST) {

    switch ($_POST['type']) {

        case 'item.create' :
            $item           = PodioItem::get($_POST['item_id']);
            doMyStuff('create',$item);
        break;

        case 'item.update' :            
            $item           = PodioItem::get($_POST['item_id']);
            doMyStuff('update',$item);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the case to verify your webhook:

```
case 'hook.verify':
    PodioHook::validate($_POST['hook_id'], array('code' => $_POST['code']));
break;
```

Try this, i'm sure it will work!